# Cant 'observeOn' main thread with RxKotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin, kotlin-interop

I'm trying to observe observable on main thread by using:

```
    // Kotlin Code
    Observable
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

but I'm getting following error:

```
    Type Mismatch:
      Required: rx.Scheduler!
      Found: io.reactivex.Scheduler!
```

The Observable I'm subscribing to is from a Library that is written in Java and therefore uses RxJava.

Am i being stupid and missing something? I'm puzzeled :$

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/348 might this help?
What's your rx related imports?

Comment: Thanks, @Ascorbin. That issue post did help and I realised that the library I was using imported 'rx.Observable', so I changed it to 'io.reactivex.Observable' but that hasn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

```
  Required: rx.Scheduler!
```

`Required` means the signature is `Observable.observeOn(rx.Scheduler)`

```
  Found: io.reactivex.Scheduler!
```

`Found` means the signature is `io.reactivex.Scheduler AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

This means that the `Observable` is a RxJava 1 observable, while the RxAndroid version used is built for RxJava 2. Since you mentioned that the observable is provided by a library it means that library is built using RxJava 1.

You have 3 options to fix this:

1. Figure out if the library in question has an RxJava 2 version, or contribute those updates to the project yourself.
2. Use [akarnokd/RxJava2Interop](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop) to convert the old `Observable` to RxJava 2. (`RxJavaInterop.toV2Observable(Observable);`)
3. Switch the other dependencies back to RxJava 1.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! What's weird is that I upgraded library to RxJava2 and the problem still persists.

Comment: RxJava and RxJava 2 use completely different packages, so if RxJava 1 is still available simply adding RxJava 2 as a dependency will change nothing.

Comment: Yep I Know, I switched imports from 'rx.Observable' to 'io.reactivex.Observable' also. Still no success :(

Comment: In case anyone else is receiving this error while using Retrofit, this post is helpful in resolving retrofit RxJava1 to RxJava2 errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434073/unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-io-reactivex-observable

Answer (score 7):

1.add :

```
   //RX JAVA
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0-RC6"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2"
```

2.Write this code :

```
  val taskObservable: Observable<Task> = Observable.fromIterable(DataSource.createTaskList())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    }
```

3.add these imports :

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable
import io.reactivex.functions.Function
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
```

**NOTE :**

if you are using KOTLIN, So it is better to use RX Kotlin!
just add two lines in your build.gradle :

```
//rxkotlin
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2"
```

Answer (score 5):

please include this in your gradle import

```
rxandroid_version="2.0.1"

implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid_version"
```

add this to your project

```
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`.subscribeOn(io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers.io())`

Comment: just a suggestion: When answering old question with multiple solutions with upvotes, try to provide some more details to understand the answer in context to the original question. Also provide the link to the documentation if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these dependencies it works for me :

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.x.x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

With:

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0"
```